# Fixed position related to the parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a very simple code to make a sticky element on scroll.

I want to make .top sticky, which is wrapped inside .wrap.
When I scroll down, I want to set the position of .top related to the wrap (so that it starts from left: 0 related to the .wrap, not related to the body. I want to keep it inside the .wrap only. How can I do that?
Thanks.

**jQuery:**

```
var top = $('.top').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y >= top){
        $('.top').addClass('sticky');
    }
    else{
        $('.top').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrap{
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 1000px;
}

.top{
    background: green;
    height: 100px;
}

.sticky{
    position: fixed;    
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/63cFy/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following CSS:

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    width: inherit;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/63cFy/1/

---

**P.S:** As [@jsmorph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317341/fixed-position-related-to-the-parent-container/#comment28611614_19317397) mentioned you could also add `top: 0` to make the element [look better](http://jsfiddle.net/63cFy/7/) on scrolling.

Comment: `top: 0;` would help though

Comment: @jsmorph It depends on which position the OP wants the sticky element appear.

Comment: Never Came across this problem, but learned something new today. +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/63cFy/4/)**

**css**

```
.wrap{
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 1000px;
}

.top{
    background: green;
    height: 100px;
}

.sticky{
   position: fixed;
    width: inherit;
    background-color:red;
}
```