# Fixed floating sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to create a fixed sidebar, very similar to that (in terms of functionality) of Apple's. When you configure your mac in their store, as you scroll down the page the basket on the right is fixed positioned; *perfectly*.

`position:fixed` is relative to the viewport and not it's parent container so what kind of scripting is going on in the background to *perfectly* position the sidebar?

(emphasis on perfectly). http://store.apple.com/uk/buy-mac/mac-pro?product=ME253B/A&step=config#

Answer (score 1):

It is done using `position:sticky`.

`.slider-content #secondary.sticky {
    position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -ms-sticky;
    position: -o-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}`

You can read more about it [here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit)

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, however Chrome doesn't seem to like it and marks it as an invalid property in the inspector.

Comment: Yes - I've checked in Safari. In Chrome it is listening for scroll event and swaps `position:absolute` to `position:fixed` after user will reach specific amount of page. Take a look on `<div id="secondary" class="rail">`, after you will scroll it is getting new class `stuck` which is setting position fixed on this element.

Comment: Which then leads back to my question, position:fixed is relative to the viewport and not the parent container; how is it calculating where to position it?

Comment: It is always at the top of viewport (when scrolled) so it has `top:0`. If you are thinking about calculating scroll this is done by adding listened to scroll function `window.addEventListener('scroll', function () { if (window.scrollY > x) {document.getElementById('secondary').classList.add('stuck')})` where x is number of pixels scrolled after which box should "stick" to viewport top.

Comment: I mean calculating it's X position in the viewport

Comment: @leaksterrr - if you don't set `left` or `right` it will default to `auto` meaning that element will be displayed where it would have had if it wasn’t positioned.

Answer (score 0):

Found this in another post:

```
http ://jsfiddle.net/63cFy

( source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19317397/3378288 )
```

As i see on your example page apple is doing the same thing. They're adding a class to the element when someone scrolls down and its not in the view anymore. The positioning in this case is relative to the "wrap" div container.

Answer (score 0):

I've done by switching between 'fixed' and 'absolute' regarding the document's body scrollTop.

```
function scrollFunction() {
    var scrollPos = document.body.scrollTop;

    if (scrollPos > 40) {
        document.getElementById("fixed-floater").style.position = "fixed";
        document.getElementById("fixed-floater").style.top = "0px";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("fixed-floater").style.position = "absolute";
        document.getElementById("fixed-floater").style.top = "40px";
    }
}

window.onscroll = scrollFunction;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ua4fhrzy/

I tried to avoid jquery if someone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Bootstrap affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix). It's also what's used in their right menu.